# How to get Top N values based on repetition from a list in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, java-stream

I am trying to get Top N values based on repetition from a list in Java.

**Example:** Find Top 2 values

[ "strawberries", "orange", "apple", "mango", "grapes", "pineapple", "mango", "strawberries", "mango", "apple"]

**Result:**
["mango"]   //mango repeated 3 times
["strawberries", "apple"]  // "strawberries", "apple" repeated 2 times each

I have written below code to acheive this

```
private static List<List<String>> getTop(int n, List<String> values) {

    Map<String, Long> valueCountMap = values.stream()
                           .collect(groupingBy(x -> x, counting()));

    final Map<String, Long> sortedByCount = valueCountMap.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.<String, Long>comparingByValue().reversed())
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue, (x, y) -> y, LinkedHashMap::new));

    List<List<String>> topNValues = new ArrayList<>();
    long prevValue = -1;
    for (Map.Entry<String, Long> e : sortedByCount.entrySet()) {
        if (prevValue == -1 || prevValue != e.getValue()) {
            if (topNValues.size() == n) {
                break;
            }
            prevValue = e.getValue();
            List<String> keys = new ArrayList<>();
            keys.add(e.getKey());
            topNValues.add(keys);
        } else if (prevValue == e.getValue()) {
            List<String> keys = topNValues.get(topNValues.size() - 1);
            keys.add(e.getKey());
        }
    }

    return topNValues;
}
```

I want to know if there is a better way of implementing this. Both performance and implementation wise.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this.

```
private static List<List<String>> getTop(int n, List<String> values) {
    return values.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s, Collectors.counting()))
        .entrySet().stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Entry::getValue,
            TreeMap::new,
            Collectors.mapping(Entry::getKey, Collectors.toList())))
        .descendingMap().values().stream()
        .limit(n)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Input

```
[strawberries, orange, apple, mango, grapes, pineapple, mango, strawberries, mango, apple]
```

Result of first `.collect()`.

```
{orange=1, apple=2, pineapple=1, strawberries=2, grapes=1, mango=3}
```

Result of second `.collect()`.

```
{1=[orange, pineapple, grapes], 2=[apple, strawberries], 3=[mango]}
```

Result of `.descendingMap()`

```
{3=[mango], 2=[apple, strawberries], 1=[orange, pineapple, grapes]}
```

Result of last `.collect()`

```
[[mango], [apple, strawberries]]
```

Comment: The use of `TreeMap` and `descendingMap` is a good use of the API. (y)

Answer (score 1):

What you seem to be looking for is really a `List<Set<String>>` as an output. A simplification to is possible if you have ranked entries based on the counting you've performed to start off with:

```
private static List<Set<String>> getTopN(int n, List<String> values) {
    Map<String, Long> valueCountMap = values.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(x -> x, Collectors.counting()));

    Map<Long, Set<String>> rankedEntries = values.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(valueCountMap::get, Collectors.toSet()));

    return rankedEntries.entrySet().stream()
            .sorted(Map.Entry.<Long, Set<String>>comparingByKey().reversed())
            .limit(n)
            .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

In terms of performance, you already have a decent algorithm to obtain the result. In the above solution for a input of N elements, this would iterate `N` times for counting, then `N` times performs a lookup on the frequency map and later iterate `rankedEntries` which is always `< N`, so you would end up with the complexity of `O(N)` overall.

Comment: sorting is not `always <N` :)